# Why the Wu-sprung model is not accepted as a solution to Riemann HYpothesis ??

Tags: number-theory, spectral-theory, mathematical-physics, riemann-hypothesis

in the Wu-sprung model, given a Hamiltonian in one dimension

$$ -y''(x)+f(x)y(x)=E_{n}y(x) \qquad y(0)=0=y(\infty) $$

we can define the function $ f(x) $ implicitly as

$$ f^{-1}(x)= 2\sqrt{\pi} \frac{d^{1/2}}{dx^{1/2}}n(x) $$

here $ n(x) $ is the function counting the eigenvalues $ n(x)= \sum_{E_{n}\le x} 1$

for the case of Riemann function this $ n(x)= \frac{1}{\pi}arg\xi(1/2+i \sqrt{x}) $

so the Riemann Hypotheis is the solution to an inverse problem

literature:  http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0510341v1.pdf  introduction to wu sprung model

http://mathdl.maa.org/images/upload_library/22/Ford/JosephKeller.pdf

a survey on inverse problems in physics

for the Riemann zet function the 'potential ' $ f(X) $ is defined as

$$  f^{-1} (x)=\frac{4}{\sqrt{4x+1} } +\frac{1}{2\pi } \int\nolimits_{-\sqrt{x} }^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{dr}{\sqrt{x-r^2} } \left( \frac{\Gamma '}{\Gamma } \left( \frac{1}{4} +\frac{ir}{2} \right) -\ln \pi \right)  -\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Lambda (n)}{\sqrt{n} } J_0 \left( \sqrt{x} \ln n\right) $$

Comment: Also posted to (and quickly closed at) MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/120017/why-mathematicians-do-not-accept-the-wu-sprung-semiclassical-model-as-a-solution

Comment: It is not accepted because it causes too many typos. HYpothesis, Hypotheis, imverse, RIemann, zet.

Comment: i meant the equations, which are the ones that are really important :D

Comment: There are also typos in the equations. I see a left parenthesis with no matching right parenthesis.

Comment: typos corrected :) ..the idea is that the Riemann-Weil trace is just equal to the Gutzwiller trace of a dynamical system..

Comment: You corrected three of the six that I pointed out.

Comment: if we take the fractional derivative operator $ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{d^{1/2}}{dx^{1/2}} $ inside the equation for $ f^{-1}(X) $ you get the Riemann-Weil formula for the density of the zeros.

Comment: Is there a proof that Gutzwiller's formula applies to this potential?

Comment: the potential is obtained from Riemann-Weil trace formula which is analogue to Gutzwiller's :)

Comment: HERE is a survey made by me about this problem and how the Riemann Weil and gutzwiller trace are analogue :) http://www.vixra.org/pdf/1301.0078v2.pdf see the analogy between the Guzwiller trace and riemann weil summation formulae in QM

Comment: Thanks for the Vixra paper, it looks interesting.  However, a sequence of formal calculations is very far from a proof that all of the calculations are controlled or have the necessary properties to imply the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is: "Because it is not". // Note that on MO, Henry Cohn commented: *The Wu-Sprung and Slater articles do not give anything like a proof of the Riemann hypothesis, nor do they (...) claim to*.

Comment: so you mean is false because you are assuming exist an hermitian operator whose trace formula of $ \delta (E-H) $ exists and is equal to the Riemann-weil formula. But is not possible to assume or consider Riemann Hypothesis as an inverse problem ?, for example find an Hermitian operator $ -y''(x)+q(X)y(x) $ whose eigenvalues are the Riemann zeros or similar.

Comment: The physics formulas and arguments used in this type of paper usually are not proved to be correct, or they are proved to be correct under some assumptions that are not true (or not proved to be true) in the case where the formula is used to reason about the Riemann hypothesis.  For example, a trace formula is applied to operators that are not of trace class.  Or a series is written down that could diverge, and the proof of convergence is missing (and in fact equivalent to what one is trying to prove using the series).

Comment: but you can always truncate a divergent series can't you ?? .. also from the potential i have deduced the Riemann weil trace formula

Comment: Having an "explicit formula" for sums over the zeros is relatively generic for Dirichlet series with analytic continuation, it does not imply anything about the location of the zeros.

Comment: thi is not only a trace formula i provide also a HERMITIAN operator whose eigenvalues are the Riemann zeros.

Comment: I did not see a clear distinction in the paper between formulas that are exact, well-defined, and analytically controlled, and formulas that are asymptotic, semiclassical, and/or uncontrolled. If there is a precisely defined operator acting on a precisely defined Hilbert space and nothing equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis is required to state or prove the necessary properties, the page and line number where that appears would be nice to know.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, that MO link is defunct.

Comment: @zyx, yes, the question and comments were recently deleted. A few comments up, Did quotes the substantive comment Henry Cohn left. It may still be possible to see the question if you type Wu-sprung site:mathoverflow.net into Google --- I'm not sure just how thoroughly deleted a deleted post to MO is.

Answer (score 3):

Where it is rigorous, the relation between quantum chaos and mathematics has been that number theory is used to prove the conjectures inspired by physics, not the other way around.  The ideas from physics are not, so far, specific enough to number theory to *prove* anything new in the direction of the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: however why do not mathematician even bother solving it numerically to check that this solution is possible ??

Comment: There is a lot of numerical computation about arithmetic quantum chaos, like anything else related to the Riemann hypothesis.  If you know of a calculation that might be new, and can be expressed in computer code, there is no reason not to do it or ask whether it is known.

Comment: http://vixra.org/pdf/1301.0078v2.pdf the operator is of the form $ H=-\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}+f(x) $ and the function $ f(x) $ is given implicitly inside (1.10) as an smooth part plus corrections due to the primes and prime powers $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Lambda (n)}{\sqrt{n}}J_{0}( \sqrt{x}logp) $

Comment: Operator on what Hilbert space?

Comment: is a problem of QM so the space is the same as the QM ... acting over integrable eigenfunctions $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx |\Psi(x)| $

Comment: @JoseGarcia "Why do not mathematician even bother..." there is no such thing as a numerical proof of the Riemann hypothesis, which makes a statement with **certainty** about the **entire** strip $0<\Re s<1$. No finite numerical check will pass muster. Mathematical arguments should pass a much higher standard of rigour than is used in physics